# clang: error: no such file or directory: 'dynamic_lookup' clang: error: no such file or directory: 'suppress'

Tags: parsing, clang, parseui

When I added the `ParseUI` lib in my Podfile, after installing pod, I have this error:

```
Ld /Users/dvs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CashCourier-ahmlxuauwynijtcqhgxogvibozet/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CashCourier.app/CashCourier normal x86_64
cd /Users/dvs/Desktop/Workspace/cash-ios
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.2
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk -L/Users/dvs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CashCourier-ahmlxuauwynijtcqhgxogvibozet/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/dvs/Desktop/Workspace/cash-ios/Pods/Parse -L/Users/dvs/Desktop/Workspace/cash-ios/Pods/TwilioSDK/Libraries -F/Users/dvs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CashCourier-ahmlxuauwynijtcqhgxogvibozet/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/dvs/Desktop/Workspace/cash-ios/Pods/Testfire/Testfire -filelist /Users/dvs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CashCourier-ahmlxuauwynijtcqhgxogvibozet/Build/Intermediates/CashCourier.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CashCourier.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CashCourier.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -read_only_relocs -undefined dynamic_lookup suppress -lBolts -lJVFloatLabeledTextField -lParse -lParseLib -lParseUI -lTwilioClient -lcrypto -llibPhoneNumber-iOS -lsqlite3 -lssl -lz -framework AVFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreVideo -framework Foundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Testfire -framework UIKit -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework Social -read_only_relocs -lBolts -lJVFloatLabeledTextField -lParse -lParseLib -lParseUI -lTwilioClient -lcrypto -llibPhoneNumber-iOS -lsqlite3 -lssl -lz -framework AVFoundation -framework Accelerate -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreTelephony -framework CoreVideo -framework Foundation -framework MobileCoreServices -framework QuartzCore -framework Security -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Testfire -framework UIKit -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework Social -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.2 -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/dvs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CashCourier-ahmlxuauwynijtcqhgxogvibozet/Build/Intermediates/CashCourier.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CashCourier.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/CashCourier_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/dvs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CashCourier-ahmlxuauwynijtcqhgxogvibozet/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CashCourier.app/CashCourier

clang: error: no such file or directory: 'dynamic_lookup'
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'suppress'
```

I tried to remove `dynamic_lookup` and suppress in my build settings, but it still gives the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by modifying the Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig file (and the same for the Pods.release.xcconfig).  Somehow, the generated xcconfig files are incorrect.

From:

```
-read_only_relocs -undefined dynamic_lookup suppress
```

To:

```
-read_only_relocs suppress -undefined dynamic_lookup
```

Comment: I had the same issues with -weak_framework Passkit. I did not have them listed next to each other, causing the clang error. I took your solution and apploed it to mine and it worked. Thanks